# Is trying to break a door considered a hostile action, as far as Sanctuary spell is concerned?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

On page 366 of Pathfinder 2e Core Rulebook, for the Sanctuary spell it states:

> You ward a creature with protective energy that deters enemy attacks. Creatures attempting to attack the target must attempt a Will save each time. If the target uses a hostile action, the spell ends."

Does trying to break a door count as a hostile action? It does not specify if the action is considered hostile only if it is directed towards a creature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Breaking down a door is generally not a Hostile Action

[Hostile Actions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=300) are defined as something that directly harms another *creature*.

> Sometimes spell effects prevent a target from using hostile actions, or the spell ends if a creature uses any hostile actions. **A hostile action is one that can harm or damage another creature, whether directly or indirectly,** but not one that a creature is unaware could cause harm. For instance, lobbing a fireball into a crowd would be a hostile action, but opening a door and accidentally freeing a horrible monster would not be. The GM is the final arbitrator of what constitutes a hostile action.

So, if you are simply trying to enter a building, your Sanctuary will (probably) remain intact. If you are attempting to break the door *into* a creature to harm it, it will not. Anything else is up to GM discretion (especially when trying to break into a building so that you can reach creatures to do harm).